# Difference between めちゃ, めちゃめちゃ, and めちゃくちゃ

Tags: meaning, nuances

These three words give me a hard time: めちゃ, めちゃめちゃ, めちゃくちゃ. Do they have distinct meanings? Do they differ in nuance? What do they actually mean.

[Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%81%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83) refers all three words back to a single meaning of めちゃくちゃ, but Jisho has multiple meanings for each word.

Comment: There are also むちゃ, むちゃくちゃ. Roughly むちゃくちゃ＝めちゃめちゃ＝めちゃくちゃ; それは無茶 is ok (unlike それはめちゃ). くちゃくちゃ is a bit different *crumpled*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

めちゃ and めっちゃ work as an adverb (めちゃ走った, めっちゃ面白い) but not as an adjective (<sup>❌</sup>めっちゃな話, <sup>❌</sup>それはめちゃだ). めちゃくちゃ and めちゃめちゃ work as both an adverb and a na-adjective, but I feel めちゃめちゃ is more common as an adverb.

めちゃくちゃ is already relatively informal, but めちゃめちゃ and め(っ)ちゃ are clearly more colloquial or slangy than めちゃくちゃ. If you used め(っ)ちゃ in a job interview, your education level would be questioned. Basically you can think of めちゃくちゃ as the standard version and the other two as slangy variants.

Meaning-wise, I think there is not a big difference. They all mean something along the lines of *crazy*, *absurd*, *mad*, *chaotic*, but can also work as an intensifier (*like crazy*, *super*, *insanely*, etc).